# WebGL + Lightbox2

Tags: javascript, html, lightbox, webgl, lightbox2

I'm trying to use Lightbox2 on a page that I have a WebGL canvas on.

So my canvas loads random images dynamically and I want to have it so that when the user double clicks on an image, it pops up with an effect like Lightbox2 has.

Right now, I have it so that when the double click event gets fired, it posts the url to the image into the console. I want to either pull from cache or re-download the image (not ideal) and display it within the Lightbox2 pop up. Then, when the user's done looking at it, they can close it and go back to viewing the canvas.

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Thanks!

Edit: [Here's a link to Lightbox2 if anyone wanted to see it](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/)

Comment: So you download image(now it is accessible by your JavaScript code) and upload it in to the GPU with webgl API but then you want to use this image in your html-css-javascript code? I can't see any problem here

Comment: IF you have some problem with data source(like if light box API receive images only from url) then you can use ["Data URI"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) but be aware of image size limitation.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you guys well, I'm very new to web programming... Is there a tutorial or something I can follow on what you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your project, the problem appears to be that Lightbox2 is designed to be activated by clicking a link. You are apparently able to get the correct URL from whatever you click on in WebGL, that's the hard part.

Next, you will need to create a link element, set it with the attributes you need, quickly add it to the DOM, trigger a click, then remove it from the DOM.

```
var TempLink = document.createElement('a');

//Set the attributes that Lightbox2 uses. Your needs will vary.
TempLink.setAttribute('href', 'your/image/url.jpg');
TempLink.setAttribute('data-lightbox', 'your-set');
TempLink.setAttribute('data-title', 'My Image Title!');

//Disable rendering, even though it shouldn't draw anyway.
TempLink.style.display = 'none';

//Add to DOM, click it, and immediately remove it.
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(TempLink);
TempLink.click();
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(TempLink);
```